# Android Geofence First Launch

Tags: android, google-maps, android-geofence

When i launch the activity for first time it cannot find my geofence location.I have specified the geofence constants in onMapReady function.What should be done to get the specified location at first app launch.

Comment: add your code so we can see

Comment: `my geofence location` ? What is a geofence location?

Comment: location coming from constants file